US comedy from early/mid 2010s, probably made for TV, with a female lead, a body on a golf course, and a date scene
Ok, this could be difficult since I only watched the last two scenes.
Anyway, it was an American movie, from the 5 years up to 2016, probably made for TV, comedy with a female lead.
Here is a description for the two scenes I watched :

The first one was on a golf course where there was a man laying on the ground, dead or unconscious, and the lead character was removing something from his body (probably a tranquilizer dart/arrow), like she was covering up something.  While doing this, two men, one young and one old, were waiting for her.
Then, she asks them if they'll call for help or whether she should before she starts fake screaming "Help! Help!"
After that, an officer questioned her for a few seconds before asking her if she's with (in a relationship with) the younger man who answers "No". Then the officer asked her out!

The last scene in the movie is in a family home where her family or friends were setting her up with a guy (a blind date).
The guy starts the date with saying "I want to have children too!".
Then she receives a call (it might have been a fake call) and says she is needed at work and leaves. An older woman tried to convince her to stay then shrugged it off (approving with her decision to leave).
The movie ends with the lead walking out from the house while saying something, maybe an uplifting message, in a voice-over.


Also, the movie gave a bit of "Hallmark movies" vibe, and I think the lead actress may have looked like Jenna Dewan Tatum, Jessica Lowndes or Marla Sokoloff.

You remember two scenes from five years ago, but not whether the actors were famous or not. Why is knowing the title of a movie important? It must be a fairly obscure one if it has never been repeated on TV. Was it funny the movie, or cringingly awful? From the description it sounds like a spy or cop story. Did the lead actress make cupcakes for a living by any chance :) OK, not Bridesmaids Check this list: http://www.imdb.com/list/ls057015344/ 197 titles!

The movie itself is from the last 5 years, that's not when I watched it and I obviously didn't recognize any of the actors. It was a humorous movie and I want to know the name so I can watch it from the beginning, also it seemed more about dating not a spy or cop story (hence it ended with a blind date and the cop asked her out)

@madmada do you recall which network or station you watched it on?

I do, but it's a channel airs in my country/region and they don't have a "published version" of their past programming schedule. I found unofficial one a while back but it was incomplete and I didn't find the movie in it.

Hmm, I vaguely remember in the early 2010s there was a fad of comedy-dramas where gangs of likable scam artists set up complex long-cons (but in a good way somehow,  with a conveniently flexible moral code),  trying to replicate the success of Hustle etc. These scenes sounds like that kind of "elaborate con" set up? Not sure if that helps  but it might help on down the genre at least.
